# How to check if an element in the list exists in another list

Tags: python

How to check if an element in the list exists in another list?And if it does append it to another list.How Can i make it to get all the values in a list?

```
common=[]

def findCommon(interActor,interActor1):
    for a in interActor:
        if a in interActor1:
            common.append(a)
    return common
interActor=['Rishi Kapoor','kalkidan','Aishwarya']
interActor1=['Aishwarya','Suman Ranganathan','Rishi Kapoor']
```

Comment: You need to put the `common` initialization inside the function. Then assign the function result to a variable when you call it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using list comprehensions:

```
common = [x for x in iter_actor1 if x in iter_actor2]
```

or using sets:

```
common = set(iter_actor1).intersection(iter_actor2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interActor=['Rishi Kapoor','kalkidan','Aishwarya']
interActor1=['Aishwarya','Suman Ranganathan','Rishi Kapoor']
anotherlist = []

for x in interActor:
    if x in interActor1:
        anotherlist.append(x)
```

Comment: It should be in a function so it can be used more than once.